# connection between server of know IP to servers of unknown IP

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, connection, ip

I have server (**server_hosted**) hosted somewhere with an IP or domain name. It is running web application. I have many other servers (**unknown_servers**) running at my home (unknown IPs) connected to router via internet.

How can I transfer data between **server_hosted** and **unknown_servers**.

Is possible to do with curl or socket any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Which data you wanna tramsfer? If your web server runs ssh - you can use scp command runnin on uknown_server. If you want to access unknown_server from known_server - you need to set up reverse nat on your router to transfer traffic from his public to specific private address (in your case to uknown_servers).
Let us know if it is help you.

Comment: Using scp it would help. But in my case I want bidirectional communication. Similar as remote login software as teamviewer. In unknown_servers I will install some of program client code (socket programming) made in C/C++ which will send request to known server. In known_server I will have server listener code, which will run always to learn on that port. From know server I will send 8 byte of data like init to client (unknown_servers). Getting init command to client.

Comment: It will initialized parameters. Now real data transfer begin. Known_server will send 8 bytes data every time when user send request from web application, request could be: open, close, init 0 etc...And getting those command to client (unknown_servers) client will perform required activities. With single client it works. But when there are multiple it doesn't because port is occupied. Using simple socket programming between client and server it is working. But problem with simple socket programming client close socket after transfer. Need to work for multiple clients